# Cannot see traceback when running python script from AutoIT

Tags: python, autoit

I have written a AutoIt-script that runs python-script. However, the python-script crashes, but I cannot see the traceback because the window closes too fast.

This is my AutoIt code:

```
Func MaestroRunner()
    run("C:\Program Files (x86)\Maestro\Mca32.exe")
    WinWaitActive("Maestro")
    sleep(3000)
    WinMenuSelectItem("[TITLE:Maestro]", "", "&Services", "&Job Control...")
    Send("c:\users\Marten\Maestrojobs\CurrentJob.job")
    Send("{Enter}")
    sleep(3000)
    RunWait(@ComSpec & " /c C:\Users\Marten\Python\Projekt\controlb.py")
EndFunc
```

controlb.py works fine if i run it manualy by the command prompt. Is there some way to get around this?

Comment: Have you tried to execute a `pause` after your command as well by concatenating the two commands with `&`, `&&` or `|`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [StdoutRead](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StdoutRead.htm) to capture console output of the Python script.